# Filter works but there is no change in UI. AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am making an online food ordering site using **AngularJS**. What I want to do is change the filter by clicking on category tabs. This is my code:

```
shoppingCart.prototype.changeFilter = function (cat) {
    var ref = document.getElementById("refresh");
     category = cat;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu-filter-list list-inline margin-b-40 text-center">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="cart.changeFilter(null)" id="refresh">All</a>
            </li>
            <li data-filter=".{{product.category}}" ng-repeat="product in store.products | unique:'category'" >
                <a ng-click="cart.changeFilter(product.category)">
                    {{product.category}}
                    <span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The filter is applied on `ng-click="cart.changeFilter(product.category)"`

**UPDATE:** **controller.js**

```
'use strict';

// the storeController contains two objects:
// - store: contains the product list
// - cart: the shopping cart object
function storeController($scope, $routeParams, DataService) {

    // get store and cart from service
    $scope.store = DataService.store;
    $scope.cart = DataService.cart;

    // use routing to pick the selected product
    if ($routeParams.productSku != null) {
        $scope.product = $scope.store.getProduct($routeParams.productSku);
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

// App Module: the name OnlineOrders matches the ng-app attribute in the main <html> tag
// the route provides parses the URL and injects the appropriate partial page
var storeApp = angular.module('OnlineOrders', ['ui']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/store', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/store.htm',
        controller: storeController,
      }).
      when('/products/:productSku', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/product.htm',
        controller: storeController
      }).
      when('/cart', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/shoppingCart.htm',
        controller: storeController
      }).
      when('/processing', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/processingOrder.htm',
          controller: storeController
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/store'
      });
}]);

// create a data service that provides a store and a shopping cart that
// will be shared by all views (instead of creating fresh ones for each view).
storeApp.factory("DataService", function () {

    // create store
    var myStore = new store();

    // create shopping cart
    var myCart = new shoppingCart("OnlineOrders");

    myCart.addCheckoutParameters("Stripe", "pk_test_9iwiq8RA0aacvfi350h76350");

    // return data object with store and cart
    return {
        store: myStore,
        cart: myCart
    };
});
```

I have added my **controller.js** and **app.js**.

Can anyone please help me figuring out why the UI is not changing?

Comment: So, where is the filter used? and maybe you mean `$scope.category = cat` instead of `category = cat`?

Comment: hi @tsh, thankyou for reply. The filter is used in `ng-click = "cart.changeFilter(product.category)"`. I tried `$scope.category = cat` but it is showing an error `$scope` is not defined.

Comment: You need to have $scope injected into the controller before you can use it, could you try setting up a plunker so we have something to help guide you with.

Comment: hi @CraigOldfield, i tried setting up plunker but didn't succeeded. Shall i provide the github link? Will it help?

Comment: It can't hurt, just provide as much detail as possible so we can help you the best we can. Im mostly interested in the structure of your controllers etc.

Comment: @CraigOldfield, I have updated my question with controller and app. Kindly check please